# Como customizar o ShowcaseView?

Tags: android, android-studio

Olá, estou tendo algumas dificuldades para utilizar a seguinte biblioteca https://github.com/JesusM/ShowcaseViewLibrary já procurei em guias, vídeos inclusive a documentação proposta.

Porém não consigo utilizar determinados métodos, pois o android studio não os reconhece. E para ser um pouco mais específico,  gostaria de saber como faço pra customizar transparências(cor), ou como realizar a animação do dedo virtual.

obs: Já importei a biblioteca e tudo mais, inclusive consegui usar e apontar as targets. Usei o seguinte guia http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2419939

De acordo com a documentação, a troca de cores é realizada da seguinte maneira

```
<style name="ShowcaseViewTheme" parent="ShowcaseView.Light">
 <item name="sv_backgroundColor">#fffff</item>
</style>
```

Fiz exatamente da forma que foi mostrada acima, porém ele não reconhece esse sv_backgroundColor, por acaso é preciso declarar esse style ou esse item em algum lugar?

Comment: Pode dar exemplos do problema?

Comment: Bom, são duas as minhas dúvidas primeiro, gostaria de saber se as Apis de estão ou não depreciadas no AndroidStudio o que explicaria o porque de ele não reconhecer determinados métodos.

Comment: E segundo com relação ao que expliquei ali, como poderia realizar a troca de cores no showcaseview via xml. Já edito o primeiro post e tento mostrar oque não funcionou, ao menos não para mim.

Comment: Por favor poste o arquivo inteiro do styles.xml, voce editou o arquivo da pasta values-v14 ou values? Voce esta rodando ele em qual versao do android? - Respondendo a pergunta, sim acredito eu que ShowcaseView esteja depreciado, mas nao quer dizer que nao funcione.